# Something like conditional routing in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Consider I have 3 screens namely screen 1, screen 2, screen 3 and screen 4.

I want to achieve the following.

```
Screen 3 is opened by Screen 1 -> BackButton -> Screen 2
Screen 3 is opened by Screen 2 -> BackButton -> Screen 3
Screen 3 is opened by Screen 4 -> BackButton -> Screen 1
```

Moreover, iOS automatically sets a swipe back option. I want to overwrite it that a swipe back in iOS does the same as described above.

Is there something like conditional routing in Flutter which helps me to adjust the BackButton-behaviour in accordance to 'from which Screen was my current Screen opened (navigator.push)'?

Comment: Thought that's pretty clear based on the heading and my description. I updated it to a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your widget tree in a `WillPopScope()` widget. This widget has an `onWillPop` property that you can override to whatever you want - in this case, depending on the screen you're on you'll probably want to override it to

```
onWillPop: () => Navigator.pushReplacement(<correctScreenWidget>)
```

This should catch any attempts to go back and instead do whatever you override it to. Be sparing with it, overriding default back button behaviour can make for a weird user experience if done poorly.

As for the conditional part of it, unfortunately it's a bit tricky as `Navigator._history` is private, so we can't just check the previous route that way. Best bet is to set up a `NavigatorObserver` to keep track of previous routes, and set the name in the `RouteSettings` of each of your routes to keep track.

Step one is to create an observer and provide it to your `Navigator`, something like this:

```
class PreviousRouteObserver extends NavigatorObserver {
  Route _previousRoute;

  Route get previousRoute => _previousRoute;
  String get previousRouteName => _previousRoute.settings.name;

  @override
  void didPush(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic> previousRoute) {
    _previousRoute = previousRoute;
  }

  @override
  void didReplace({Route<dynamic> newRoute, Route<dynamic> oldRoute}) {
    _previousRoute = oldRoute;
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final PreviousRouteObserver observer = PreviousRouteObserver();
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page', observer: observer),
      navigatorObservers: [
        observer,
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Note that `MyHomePage` above needs to accept the observer as an argument so you can access it. Alternatively you could set up an `InheritedWidget` or something to maintain access to it, but this answer is getting a little long already so I'll leave that for a later question.

Then, when providing `Routes` to your Navigator, ensure you've got a name in the `RouteSettings`:

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(
  context, 
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => NextScreen(observer: widget.observer),
    settings: RouteSettings(name: "nextScreen"),
  ),
);
```

Finally, do conditional routing based on the current value of `widget.observer.previousRouteName` in any widget that has access to it. This is just a simple matter of a `switch` or something in your `onWillPop`, so I'll leave that to you.

Kind of unfortunate that it's so roundabout, but it looks like this might be your best option at the moment. Hope it helps!

Comment: Any idea how to do the conditional thing? So if I am opening a screen from Screen 1, overwrite with `onWillPop: () => Navigator.pushReplacement(<SecondScreen>)` and if I am opening the same screen from Screen 4, overwrite with `onWillPop: () => Navigator.pushReplacement(<ThirdScreen>)`

Comment: Sorry! Looks like I missed some of the original question. I've updated my answer with some examples of how to find which Route your user is coming from, this should let you set up some conditional routes that go different places based on history.

Comment: WillPopScope only accepts Future<bool>, and not Future<Object>. So onWillPop: () => Navigator.pushReplacement(<correctScreenWidget>) doesn’t work for me. Any idea?